# Slick group by with other fields

Tags: scala, slick

```
select user_id, user_name,created_at, count(id) from message group by user_id order by created_at desc;
```

I want to write sql(mysql) like the this, how to do it with slick ( not plain sql).

Comment: The "quick introduction" should [get you started](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/gettingstarted.html).

Comment: @fotNelton I have read that actually. But still not found it easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slick mimics Scala's collection API where possible. Think how you would do it in Scala collections.

```
Messages.groupBy(_.userId).map{ case (userId,group) =>
    (userId, group.userName.max, group.createdAt.max, group.size)
}.orderBy(_.createdAt)
```

(There currently is no `.head` to get a single element from a collection. Using `.max` as a fallback here.)

For obtaining the Messages object refer to the documentation, e.g. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/code-generation.html